# How to enable nameserver via VPN

Tags: 12.10, 13.04, vpn, dns, openvpn

I use VPN (openvpn) on Ubuntu 13.04. I see the IP-s through VPN correctly. The problem is, although I configure the nameserver in the network manager I still doesn't see the domains.

The exported VPN configuration says:

```
comp-lzo yes
dev tun
proto udp
nobind
auth-nocache
script-security 2
persist-key
persist-tun
user openvpn
group openvpn
```

`/etc/resolv.conf` says it will be rewritten, so I don't edit it

`/etc/network/interfaces` contains only:

```
# interfaces(5) file used by ifup(8) and ifdown(8)
auto lo
iface lo inet loopback
```

I tried editing:

`/etc/dhcp/dhclient.conf`

by adding:

```
interface "eth0" {
        prepend domain-name-servers MY.DNS.IP.ADDRESS;
}
```

But it doesn't work.

How can I solve it?

Answer (score 1):

The OpenVPN **server** should push appropriate options with dhcp. Just like your router does when you connect over wifi. From my `/etc/openvpn/server.conf`:

```
# DNS servers, courtesy of Google
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.8.8"
push "dhcp-option DNS 8.8.4.4"
```

Comment: Well, the server configuration should be OK -- it works with Windows, it works with some older Ubuntu (11.10, I guess) of one of my co-workers.

Comment: The issue is that in 12.04, Ubuntu released (as I understand it) Network Manager and Resolveconf on a previously happy world - and it doesn't seem to add the DNS addresses correctly regardless of pushing them across.  I'm having the same problem as Kalmar - I have the tunnel working fine, but unless I manually hack resolv.conf and put the DNS server for the network at the other end of the tunnel above the localhost entry I just can't resolve anything on the far end of the tunnel.  Ubuntu used to be such a good OS... what happened?